# PyCharm debugger stops working after usage of df.to_sql

Tags: python, pycharm, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm having difficulty getting my PyCharm debugger to work properly in my flask app.  I have functions which are initializing datasets in a remote sqlite database.  I am working outside of the typical flask-sqlalchemy class framework because they are not interfacing with the GUI, so I don't need to have that overhead.

I am able to successfully write to the database using:

```
admin_df.to_sql(df_name, con=db.engine, if_exists="replace", chunksize=500, index=False)
```

For some odd reason, my PyCharm debugger is stopping to work after:

```
admin_df = pd.read_sql_table(admin_df_name, con=db.engine)
```

Would any of you have insights into why this behaviour with the debugger is occurring?  Looking at my database, the dataset is being created correctly, but a subsequent "write" in the same manner is not.  Unfortunately I can't deduce that second aspect because my breakpoints aren't working, and no errors are occurring in my log.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the answer to that but there are a few things you can do.

1. When debugging there's this gear icon below "View Breakpoints". There you can change "Variable Loading Policy" to "On Demand". It resolved some of my weird PyCharm debugger issues.
2. If your df is huge you may want to add chunksize.

`df.to_sql('table', engine, chunksize=chunksize)`

3. > the dataset is being created correctly, but a subsequent "write" in the same manner is not

Before running this command you can ping your DB to make sure you have a connection.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  I attempted the amendment to "on demand".  Unfortunately it is still not stopping at subsequent breakpoints.  I did also add a chunksize with the same outcome.

Answer (score 0):

The error seems linked to a general inability of my PyCharm editor to report breaks and error messages.  I have posted a separate question.